# SFMC custom activity error: Contacts not pushed through Custom Flow Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

We are building a custom JB activity that does a Lookup for the branchResult of all the users in a Data Extension from an External JSON object and push the contacts based on the response. We have followed the same steps as mentioned on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm and hosted web app on Heroku.

The activity is successfully validated and runs fine till the contacts enter the custom activity, after which they just remain stuck there and do not progress in the journey.

We are working based on the tutorial by Markus Slabina [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

We are attaching the following files

- **config.json** - The config file for the journey

```
    {
        "key": <key value>,
        "metaData": {
            "icon": "images/icon.png",
            "iconSmall": "images/icon_small.png"
        },
        "type": "RESTDECISION",
        "lang": {
            "en-US": {
                "name": "Marketing Cloud Custom Split",
                "description": "Custom Split activity that makes a decision based on data from Marketing Cloud"
            }
        },
        "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
        "configurationArguments": {
            "applicationExtensionKey": <key value>,
            "save": {
                "url": "https://<URL where app is hosted>/activity/save",
                "verb": "POST",
                "body": "",
                "useJwt": true
            },
            "publish": {
                "url": "https://<URL where app is hosted>/activity/publish",
                "verb": "POST",
                "body": "",
                "useJwt": true
            },
            "validate": {
                "url": "https://<URL where app is hosted>/activity/validate",
                "verb": "POST",
                "body": "",
                "useJwt": true
            }
        },
        "wizardSteps": [{
                "key": "eventdefinitionkey",
                "label": "Event Definition Key"
            },
            {
                "key": "idselection",
                "label": "ID Selection"
            }
        ],
        "outcomes": [{
                "arguments": {
                    "branchResult": "verylikely"
                },
                "metaData": {
                    "label": "Very Likely"
                }
            },
            {
                "arguments": {
                    "branchResult": "likely"
                },
                "metaData": {
                    "label": "Likely"
                }
            },
            {
                "arguments": {
                    "branchResult": "neutral"
                },
                "metaData": {
                    "label": "Neutral"
                }
            },
            {
                "arguments": {
                    "branchResult": "unlikely"
                },
                "metaData": {
                    "label": "Unlikely"
                }
            }
        ],
        "userInterfaces": {
            "runningModal": {
                "url": "runningModal.html"
            },
            "runningHover": {
                "url": "runningHover.html"
            }
        },
        "arguments": {
            "execute": {
                "inArguments": [],
                "outArguments": [],
                "url": "https://<URL where app is hosted>/activity/execute",
                "verb": "POST",
                "body": "",
                "header": "",
                "format": "json",
                "useJwt": true,
                "timeout": 90000
            }
        },
        "edit": {
            "url": "https://mslabina-jb.herokuapp.com/index.html",
            "height": 200,
            "width": 500
        }
    }
```

- **server.js** - Server file that has POST call handlers for /execute, /validate etc.

```
    "use strict";

    const Path = require("path");
    const Pkg = require(Path.join(__dirname, "..", "package.json"));
    const express = require("express");

    // Helper utility for verifying and decoding the jwt sent from Salesforce Marketing Cloud.
    const verifyJwt = require(Path.join(__dirname, "lib", "jwt.js"));
    // Helper class that handles all the interactions with Salesforce Service Cloud
    // and makes sure open connections are reused for subsequent requests.

    const MarketingCloud = require(Path.join(__dirname, "lib", "extractScript.js"));
    const sfmc = new MarketingCloud();


    const app = express();

    // Register middleware that parses the request payload.
    app.use(
        require("body-parser").raw({
            type: "application/jwt"
        })
    );

    // Route that is called for every contact who reaches the custom split activity
    app.post("/activity/execute", (req, res) => {
        verifyJwt(
            req.body,
            Pkg.options.salesforce.marketingCloud.jwtSecret,
            (err, decoded) => {
                // verification error -> unauthorized request
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return res.status(401).end();
                }

                if (decoded && decoded.inArguments && decoded.inArguments.length > 0) {
                    let marketingCloudId;
                    var decodedArgs = decoded.inArguments[0];
                    marketingCloudId = decodedArgs.customerKey;

                    // Call the function that retrieves desired data from JSON
                    sfmc.retrieveSegmentValue(marketingCloudId, (err, fieldValue) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            return res.status(500).end();
                        }

                        // Check the returned value to make the decision which path should be
                        // followed and return the branchResult accordingly.
                        if (fieldValue === "verylikely") {
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                branchResult: "verylikely"
                            });
                        } else if (fieldValue === "likely") {
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                branchResult: "likely"
                            });
                        } else if (fieldValue === "unlikely") {
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                branchResult: "unlikely"
                            });
                        } else {
                            return res.status(200).json({
                                branchResult: "neutral"
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error("inArguments invalid.");
                    return res.status(400).end();
                }
            }
        );
    });

    // Routes for saving, publishing and validating the custom activity. In this case
    // nothing is done except decoding the jwt and replying with a success message.
    app.post(/\/activity\/(save|publish|validate)/, (req, res) => {
        verifyJwt(
            req.body,
            Pkg.options.salesforce.marketingCloud.jwtSecret,
            (err, decoded) => {
                // verification error -> unauthorized request
                if (err) return res.status(401).end();

                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true
                });
            }
        );
    });

    // Serve the custom activity's interface, config, etc.
    app.use(express.static(Path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")));

    // Start the server and listen on the port specified by heroku or defaulting to 12345
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 12345, () => {
        console.log("Customsplit backend is now running!");
    });
```

**extractScript.js** - The custom js file that we created to extract the corresponding branch values for contacts List item

```
class MarketingCloud {
    retrieveSegmentValue(id, cb) {
        var url = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/<URL where our JSON is hosted>";
        fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.body);
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (obj) {
                console.log(obj);
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj.content).length; i++) {
                    if (obj.content[i].CUSTOMER_INDID === id) {
                        return cb(undefined, obj.content[i].segmentValue);
                    } else {
                        return cb(new Error('No unique result returned.'));
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}

module.exports = MarketingCloud;
```

- **customActivity.js** - Preparing the payload for inArguments in Save function

```
'use strict';

define(function (require) {
    var Postmonger = require('postmonger');
    var connection = new Postmonger.Session();
    var payload = {};
    var steps = [{
            'key': 'eventdefinitionkey',
            'label': 'Event Definition Key'
        },
        {
            'key': 'idselection',
            'label': 'ID Selection'
        }
    ];
    var currentStep = steps[0].key;
    var eventDefinitionKey = '';
    var deFields = [];

    $(window).ready(function () {
        connection.trigger('ready');
        connection.trigger('requestInteraction');
    });

    function initialize(data) {
        if (data) {
            payload = data;
        }
    }

    function onClickedNext() {
        if (currentStep.key === 'idselection') {
            save();
        } else {
            connection.trigger('nextStep');
        }
    }

    function onClickedBack() {
        connection.trigger('prevStep');
    }

    function onGotoStep(step) {
        showStep(step);
        connection.trigger('ready');
    }

    function showStep(step, stepIndex) {
        if (stepIndex && !step) {
            step = steps[stepIndex - 1];
        }

        currentStep = step;

        $('.step').hide();

        switch (currentStep.key) {
            case 'eventdefinitionkey':
                $('#step1').show();
                $('#step1 input').focus();
                break;
            case 'idselection':
                $('#step2').show();
                $('#step2 input').focus();
                break;
        }
    }


    function save() {
        payload['arguments'] = payload['arguments'] || {};
        payload['arguments'].execute = payload['arguments'].execute || {};

        var idField = deFields.length > 0 ? $('#select-id-dropdown').val() : $('#select-id').val();
        var deField = deFields.length > 0 ? $('#select-id-dropdown').val() : $('#select-id-1').val();

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
            'customerKey': '{{Contact.Attribute.' + deField + '.' + idField + '}}'
        }];

        payload['metaData'] = payload['metaData'] || {};
        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(payload));

        connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);
    }

    connection.on('initActivity', initialize);
    connection.on('clickedNext', onClickedNext);
    connection.on('clickedBack', onClickedBack);
    connection.on('gotoStep', onGotoStep);
});
```

- **result.json** - The sample json file stored on a public server

```
{
"content": [
{
"CUSTOMER_INDID": "12345",
"segmentValue": "likely"
},
{
"CUSTOMER_INDID": "12346",
"segmentValue": "unlikely"
},
{
"CUSTOMER_INDID": "12349",
"segmentValue": "unlikely"
},
{
"CUSTOMER_INDID": "12348",
"segmentValue": "neutral"
},
{
"CUSTOMER_INDID": "12347",
"segmentValue": "verylikely"
}
]
}
```

**Expected Functionality** : Contact with ID: 12345 should be sent on 'likely' branch

Contact with ID: 12345 should be sent on 'Unlikely' branch[image]
[image]

Comment: So contacts don't get stuck, they error out. I would suggest opening a support case, so they can supply you the error logs for the activity

Comment: Thanks i got the logs for the Journey. Unable to understand the issue though